# treatment for factors with many levels

Tags: binning, many-categories

I'm running a predictive model and I have one possible predictive variable that is a factor and has more than 800 levels.  I tried to reduce it running ctree in R (with the variable as the only predictive variable and the original class as class) and using the prediction to bin the variable and reduce the levels.  But ctree takes too long (and never ends). What other method would you recommend?

Comment: How many observations do you have?